# My infix helps prevent suicide, my suffix is Protocol

Tags: riddle, word

> My prefix is number 17
> My suffix is Protocol
> My infix helps prevent suicide
> My whole fastens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My prefix is number 17

> Chlorine (chemical symbol **Cl**) has the atomic number 17

My suffix is Protocol

> Internet Protocol (**IP**)

My infix helps prevent suicide

> Lithium (chemical symbol **Li**) compounds taken as medication can [reduce the risk of suicide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_(medication))

My whole fastens

> A **clip**

Comment: You're right.  It's not just with a line break.

Comment: @Ollie Do you mean it also happens when there's no line break? I can't reproduce that (Opera GX LVL2 core: 68.0.3618.206). Also [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353670/hyperlinks-in-spoilers-are-only-partially-clickable-when-a-line-break-is-in-betw) for anyone who's wondering what we're talking about

Comment: @Ollie Ah wait I can also reproduce it, but only if the link is in the first and only line.

Comment: Exactly.  Big bug.